# VBA IE automation - simulate ctrl+click

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer, browser-automation

I've got a list of names on a website that can be multi-selected by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + clicking them. A second button then loads in data for all the selected names. Normally clicking the name loads the data for just the name clicked. I'm trying to automate this process of control clicking using VBA in Excel. The HTML for the individual clickable elements is structured like so:

```
<a onkeydown="ps.onKeyDown(this);" onclick="return false;" href="#r9">
<span>Doe, John</span>
<label class="hidden-label" name="SelectInfo"></label>
```

I'm assuming that the `onkeydown="ps.onKeyDown(this);"` part is where the magic is happening. I have attempted to call this function in VBA using the following code:

```
js = Array( _
    "var input = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')(0).contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('iframe')(0).contentDocument.getElementById('psLIST_TBL_NAME').getElementsByTagName('a')(" & AgentIndex & ");", _
    "ps.onKeyDown(input);" _
)

Call IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript(Join(js, vbNewLine))
```

When running this code, I receive error **'ps' is undefined** in the Internet Explorer console. Is there another way that I can simulate a control click on individual elements in the page?

EDIT: I found the actual onKeyDown function, and it just has me more confused than before. There is no reference to the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, just <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>.

```
/**
* Handles onKeyDown event, this is for keyboard accessibility, code 508 compliance
* If SPACE is pressed, invoke onSelect (TR onClick)
* If -> is pressed, invoke onToggle (Norgie onClick)
*
* @param eSender - element that received onKeyDown event
*/
function onKeyDown( eSender ) {
    var key = Event.keyCode;
    if (key == 32) {
        //this.onSelect( sItemID );
        eSender = getParentByTagName(eSender, "TR");
        if (eSender && eSender.onclick)
            eSender.onclick.apply(eSender);//call TR onclick if applicable
    } else if (key == 39) {
        //this.onToggle( sItemID );
        eSender = getParentByTagName(eSender, "TR");
        if (!eSender)
            return;
        eSender = DOM2.getElementById(eSender.id+"Norg")
        if (eSender && eSender.onclick)
            eSender.onclick.apply(eSender);//call Norgie onclick if applicable
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG I can't believe anyone does this anymore. Nightmare alert. Oh, and `ps` **is not** defined. You didn't provide any code that initializes it. Does that exist?

Comment: How does _**on a website**_ correlate to _**using VBA in Excel**_ ?

Comment: @Randy Casburn I'd be using an API if that was an option, but unfortunately the screen scraping approach is the only way to do it.

Comment: Pretty sure @RandyCasburn's point was more about why you're not doing this in C# using an actual HTTP request instead of an IE API from 1998. That said, there's a handful of VBA web-scraping question every single day, so don't worry, you're far from being the only one doing this.

Comment: @Randy Casburn I couldn't find anywhere in the code where the ps object is initialized. But how does the onkeydown event call this function if it has not already been defined?

Comment: Can you share the link? It's not only about clicking issue but also iframe is there to be dealt with.

Comment: @SIM I wish I could. The page in question is on an intranet.

Comment: Well, in that case you should update your post with substantial `html elements` to test locally.

Comment: `ps` is in a different context/frame: `input.ownerDocument.defaultView.ps.onKeyDown(input);`

Comment: @Florent B. You are awesome! I was able to track down the javascript function that actually does the selecting and this allowed me to call it in the correct context.